# How do I display a header at the top of each cygwin terminal?

Tags: terminal, header, cygwin

Problem I have is not knowing which JVM is the active one for a given project. I want to see if I can display this in a header. How might this be accomplished?

Comment: You can use set the title before running a specific JVM https://www.askapache.com/linux/bash-power-prompt/#Changing_Window_Title_PS1

Comment: Can that be done dynamically after the window is launched? If it works, it would save me some window space but I was thinking ANSI header / footer like screen sets.